# Removing Duplicates Based date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following Query to select (will use for an update statement) remove duplicates based on the min service date and keeping the most recent svc date.

```
select st.SubID, st.RecordNo, st.Fname, st.Lname, st.MemberID,  st.ServiceDate, IsDeduped, DedupCriteria
       from stagingtable st
       join (select MemberID
                     from stagingtable
                     where SubID = 99999
                           and waveseqid = 1
                     group by MemberID
                     having count(*) > 1) st2
       on st.MemberID = st2.MemberID
       and st.ServiceDate = (Select min(ServiceDate) from stagingtable s where s.subid = 99999 and s.waveseqid = 1 and st.MemberID = s.MemberID)
where SubID = 99999
       and waveseqid = 1
       order by RecordNo
```

This seems to pull in sometime only pull in multiples with the same date for the memberid:

```
SurveyID    RecordNo    Fname   Lname   MemberID    Option9 IsDeduped   DedupCriteria
99999   1   John    Doe 123 10/1/2015   0   NULL x  These show on the query
99999   2   John    Doe 123 10/1/2015   0   NULL x  These show on the query
99999   3   John    Doe 123 10/8/2015   0   NULL But expected these as well
99999   4   John    Doe 123 10/12/2015  0   NULL But expected these as well
99999   4   John    Doe 123 10/14/2015  0   NULL But expected these as well
99999   6   John    Doe 123 10/29/2015  0   NULL But expected these as well
99999   7   John    Doe 123 12/14/2015  0   NULL But expected these as well
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "AND" statement restricts the results to only rows with the minimum service date.

```
and st.ServiceDate = (Select min(ServiceDate) from stagingtable s where s.subid = 99999 and s.waveseqid = 1 and st.MemberID = s.MemberID)
```

That's why you get two rows and not all of them.